# if clause using?

Tags: c#, if-statement

```
if (statement)
     base.Database.AddInParameter(command, "ColumnX", DbType.String, "StackOverflow");
 else
     base.Database.AddInParameter(command, "ColumnX", DbType.String, DBNull.Value);
```

I want to do this statement in one line by using

```
? "true" : "false"
```

For example:

```
if(statement) ? base.Database.AddInParameter(command, "ColumnX", DbType.String, "StackOverflow") : base.Database.AddInParameter(command, "ColumnX", DbType.String, DBNull.Value);
```

but this is not true. Visual studio says that unexpected token for " : "

any idea? thanks

Comment: For future reference this is known as the ternary operator.

Comment: What's the supposed value of having it on one line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, the `if` before `(statement)` is not needed for the [conditional operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx).

Secondly, you can't use it as both sides of the conditional need to be the same type or types where one is implicitly convertible to the other - `string` and `DBNull.Value` are not such types.

You *can* use it if you cast either the `string` or `DBNull.Value` to `object`:

```
base.Database.AddInParameter(
                             command, 
                             "ColumnX", 
                             DbType.String, 
                             statement ? "StackOverflow" : (object)DBNull.Value);
```

However, if I had to read this on one line, I would find it *less* readable than the original version you posted - there is no value in having this logic in one line, in particular if it reduces readability and makes the code less easy to understand.

Answer (score 6):

Why not do it like this (I wrapped it over many lines for SO)?

```
 base.Database.AddInParameter(
    command, 
    "ColumnX", 
    DbType.String, 
    statement ? "StackOverflow" : (Object)DBNull.Value);
```

Your attempt isn't valid C#. If you *really* want to do it your way and use an `if...else`on one line it would need to be like:

```
if(statement) base.Database.AddInParameter(command, "ColumnX", DbType.String, "StackOverflow"); else base.Database.AddInParameter(command, "ColumnX", DbType.String, DBNull.Value);
```

But that's pretty hard to read.

Even when short: `if (true) DoOne(); else DoTwo();` isn't that easy.

```
if (true) 
    DoOne(); 
else 
    DoTwo();
```

Is better.

Comment: This will not work. String and `DBNull.Value` are not convertible to each other.

Comment: DBNull.Value is not a string. Casting it to `object` first might work.

Comment: Yes it does not work, visual studio says that: there is no implicit conversion between string and System.Dbnull

Comment: @StackUser, try `statement ? "StackOverflow" : (object)DBNull.Value`

Answer (score 4):

The [ternary operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) only works for assignments.

What you could do instead is this:

```
var value = statement ? (object)"StackOverflow" : DBNull.Value;
base.Database.AddInParameter(command, "Column X", DbType.String, value);
```

Of course, you could combine this into a single statement as well (but it's actually more lines if you format it nicely):

```
base.Database.AddInParameter(
    command,
    "Column X",
    DbType.String,
    statement ? (object)"StackOverflow" : DBNull.Value);
```

Answer (score 2):

Take out the if at the beginning so it reads.

```
statement ? base.Database.AddInParameter(command, "ColumnX", DbType.String,"StackOverflow") : base.Database.AddInParameter(command,"ColumnX", DbType.String, DBNull.Value);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're only switching a string for a DBNull you should just replace that var, along the lines of:

```
var theReplacement = (statement ? (object)"StackOverflow" : DBNull.Value);

base.Database.AddInParameter(command, "ColumnX", DbType.String, theReplacement);
```